# pyodbc.ProgrammingError 42000 (8114) error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

The below is my code:

```
if data['Key']['Name'] == ".AORD" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".CBD100" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".CNT" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".CSI300" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".CSI300FS" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".DJI" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".FCHI" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".FTSE" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".GDAXI" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSCC" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSCE" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSCI" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSCIC" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSCIU" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSNC" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSNF" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSNP" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".HSTECH" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".INX" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".N255" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SPHKGEM" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SSE180" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SSE380I" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SSE50" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SSEA" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SSEB" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SZSA" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SZSB" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SZSC" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SZ100" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SZI":
    print("[", datetime.datetime.now(), "]" + data['Key']['Name'] + " Turnover: " , data['Fields']['TURNOVER'], " Value: ", data['Fields']['TRDPRC_1'])
    if data['Fields']['TURNOVER'] == None:
        sqlg = "UPDATE STOCK.dbo.Curr_Indexs SET Value=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['TRDPRC_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Net_Change=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Percent_Change=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['PCTCHNG']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , DayHigh=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['HIGH_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , DayLow=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['LOW_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , OFF_CLOSE=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['OFF_CLOSE']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Date=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "\' ,Data_Time=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "\' WHERE nRic=\'" + data['Key']['Name'] + "\'"
    if data['Fields']['TURNOVER'] != None:
        sqlg = "UPDATE STOCK.dbo.Curr_Indexs SET Value=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['TRDPRC_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Net_Change=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Percent_Change=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['PCTCHNG']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , DayHigh=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['HIGH_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , DayLow=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['LOW_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , OFF_CLOSE=CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['OFF_CLOSE']) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Turnover= CAST(\'" + str(float(data['Fields']['TURNOVER'])) + "\' AS FLOAT) , Date=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "\' ,Data_Time=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "\' WHERE nRic=\'" + data['Key']['Name'] + "\'"
                
    cur1.execute(sqlg)
    conn1.commit()
```

Does anybody knows what is the problem? The type in the data base are float(except the Date and Data_Time).
please help.
Thank you.

I know SQL injection is bad practice but it shouldn't produce this error? The below code works in the same program for reference:

```
if data['Key']['Name'] == ".NQUOTA.SH" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".NQUOTA.ZK" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SQUOTA.HS" or data['Key']['Name'] == ".SQUOTA.HZ":
    if "QUTA_REM" in data['Fields']:
        print("[", datetime.datetime.now(), "]", data['Key']['Name']  ,": QUTA_REM: ", data['Fields']['QUTA_REM'])
        sqle = "UPDATE STOCK.dbo.NorthBoundQuota SET DailyQBalance= " + str(data['Fields']['QUTA_REM']/100000) + ", Date=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "\' WHERE nRic=\'" + data['Key']['Name'] + "\'"
        cur1.execute(sqle)
        conn1.commit()
```

DailyQBalance is type float in the database.

I could see the raw JSON data and they're not None/Null/empty, they are numbers. And previously I used the below SQL and it produced the same error:

```
sqlg = "UPDATE STOCK.dbo.Curr_Indexs SET Value=\'" + str(data['Fields']['TRDPRC_1']) + "\' , Net_Change=\'" + str(data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1']) + "\' , Percent_Change=\'" + str(data['Fields']['PCTCHNG']) + "\' , DayHigh=\'" + str(data['Fields']['HIGH_1']) + "\' , DayLow=\'" + str(data['Fields']['LOW_1']) + "\' , OFF_CLOSE=\'" + str(data['Fields']['OFF_CLOSE']) + "\' , Turnover=\'" + str(float(data['Fields']['TURNOVER'])) + "\' , Date=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + "\' ,Data_Time=\'" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "\' WHERE nRic=\'" + data['Key']['Name'] + "\'"
```

Comment: Somewhere you have a string which you are trying to convert to a float, and the string is invalid, my guess is `CAST(\'" + str(data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1']) + "\' AS FLOAT`

Comment: May I ask why data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'] specifically?  Shouldn't str() already convert it to string?

Comment: You mean what's the problem aside from all the SQL Injection? If you used parameterized queries this problem probably wouldn't exist - SQL Server is likely seeing something like `CAST('None' AS FLOAT)` which would generate `Msg 8114 Level 16 State 5 Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to float.`

Comment: You're building a query which is run against the database, attempting to convert the value stored in that column to a float.

Comment: Please see edit. Thank you

Comment: data['Fields']['TRDPRC_1'] comes from a data provider. It is a websocket program that get data(in JSON format) from provider and update our own database

Comment: The second piece of code is to show that SQL injection probably has nothing to do with the error aince it works and the data is of the same type and it's updating a column that is type float as well

Comment: The second piece of code doesn't attempt to cast anything to float so of course it's not going to generate "Error converting data type varchar to float." Somewhere in the data supplied to the first piece of code the one/some/all of the TRDPRC_1, NETCHNG_1, PCTCHNG, HIGH_1, LOW_1, OFF_CLOSE, TURNOVER values are None, blank/empty string, or something otherwise un-floaty.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning please see edit2

Comment: But you still don't show us the values you are trying to update with?

Comment: @DaleK It's real time market data so it's constantly changing. But for data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1'] the value would be somthing like 0.42. For data['Fields']['TURNOVER'] it would be someting like 44164.652 or None

Comment: @DaleK Again It's real time market data so it's constantly changing. But for data['Fields']['NETCHNG_1']  it will be 0.43 etc.(NETCHNG_1 means Net_Change so it will  be from 0-1 which translates to 0-100%). For data['Fields']['TURNOVER'], the value will be  44164.652 or 50021.652 basically just number

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to use parameterized queries and it works. But what I don't understand is why some SQL injection statments work while other don't (especially when the data received has the same type as the problematic SQL statement and the columns being updated are the same (float)).

Comment: You would find out if your inspected the SQL string you were attempting to run.